Notification of File Creation in S3 bucket
I need to fetch a file from S3 from a specific folder as soon as it is created and process it in spring boot microservice. However due to some constraints SNS and SQS can't be used for notification of file creation. So looking for suggestions on what would be the best approach for this scenario.
Expecting: Due to some constraints SNS and SQS can't be used for notification of file creation in S3. So looking for suggestions on what would be the best approach for this scenario.

By definition, S3 Event Notifications can only trigger SNS, SQS, Lambda, or Event Bridge.  If you can't use SNS or SQS, then you must use Lambda or Event Bridge.

If this solution needs to scale then you should dig deeper into the SQS restriction.

What would you like to happen?
